# How to collect data from different tables and insert it in one table in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a ms-access `database` that has some tables, using C# I insert their values but at the end I want to collect data from each one of them and put these data to another table.

these is my tables:

[image]
   [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

this is how I insert FeedID from tFeeds into tFeedsRation:

```
{
string StrCon = System.Configuration....;

string InsertInto = @"INSERT INTO tFeedsRations
                    SELECT FeedID FROM tFeeds
                    WHERE tFeeds.FeedID=@id";

OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);
OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
Cmd.Connection = Connection;

Connection.Open();
Cmd.CommandText = InsertInto;
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = SelectedFeedID;
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Connection.Close();
}
```

Now my question is:

First I want to insert RationID from tRations into tFeedsRations in a same time,

And after that I want to insert these data to tFeedsRationsCows:

FeedID from tFeedsRations
RationID from tRations
CowID from tCows

Comment: This is so far from clear what you're asking. Give us the structure of your table(s), and a specific example of what you want to do.

Comment: @Jamiec Hi, I edited the question as you said